# assembly GCC R_X86_64_PC32 relocation instead of R_X86_64_GOTPCREL?

Tags: linux, assembly, gcc, linker, relocation

I'm trying to write a shared library but It seems that GCC always emit `R_X86_64_PC32` relocation which according to this [link](https://www.technovelty.org/c/position-independent-code-and-x86-64-libraries.html) it is supposed to cause an error since now the offset will be fixed and can cause an error if different libraries have same symbol name.
the library code is

```
.section .data
.section .bss
    .lcomm data, 1000
.section .text
.type cpuid, @function
.globl cpuid
cpuid:

    push %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    push %rbx

    movq $0, %rax
    cpuid
    movl %ebx, data(%rip)
    movl %edx, data+4(%rip)
    movl %ecx, data+8(%rip)

    lea data(%rip), %rax

    pop %rbx
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    pop %rbp
    ret
```

Build as `gcc -c -shared -o cpuid.o cpuid.s` also with addition of `-fPic` flag seems to always result in same kind of relocation which is `readeld -r cpuid.o`

```
000000000010  000300000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .bss - 4
000000000016  000300000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .bss + 0
00000000001c  000300000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .bss + 4
000000000023  000300000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .bss - 4
```

So my question is

1- why No error is resulted when creating shared library using `gcc -shared -o libcpuid.so  cpuid.o`

2-why GCC seems to refuse to use the GOT table even when using `-fPIC`

Comment: You used `rip` relative addressing so of course it will emit that relocation. You need to ask for a GOT relocation yourself if that's what you want.

Comment: Note that `-fPIC` only has effect on compiler code generation, not assembly you have written by hand.

Comment: @Jester thank's a lot this explains why ```GOTPCREL``` wasnt generated but isn't ```PC32``` supposed to cause problems in shared libraries

Comment: @Jester and How to produce ```GOTPCREL``` since using ```@got``` produce ```GOT32``` relocations. I know how both are calculated but can't see a reason to use one over the other so If you can explain this difference will be really good.

Comment: Look at compiler output with `-fPIC`  for C source: `foo@gotpcrel(%rip)` to access the GOT entry with a RIP-relative addressing mode.

Comment: Also, yuck, in that specific example you should just have the caller pass a pointer to an output array (so they can fill a local on the stack).  And don't forget to store the EAX output of CPUID.  If you just want a minimal example that only demos accessing a global array with symbol-interposition supported (by going through the GOT), leave out the CPUID.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks alot but does this mean that ```PC32``` is allowed in shared libraries in Linux since this means that the library must be loaded in lower 32 bit space right ? I'm asking since in the posted link it says that ```PC32``` is not allowed when using shared libraries.

Comment: *but does this mean that PC32 is allowed in shared libraries* - no, x86-64 shared libraries don't support loading in the low 32 bits, AFAIK.  Maybe with a custom ld.so or dlopen or something?  I think that relocation will fail at run-time if you link it against an executable normally.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks alot I got it now